# Mocking a server for swift app

Tags: swift, mvvm, mocking, rx-swift, moya

I have a swift project that I am working on .

The backend for it is still not ready so I thought of hosting the server in the app such that I can make a request and have the responses stored with in the app.

Whenever user makes a request the mocked response is displayed.

Is there any tutorial that I can find on how to do this .

I am using the mvvm architecture and Moya for making network calls.

I am familiar with making network calls and parsing it to display responses.

It will be great if anyone could point out to a tutorial on hooking it up with a mocked server within the app.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: the easiest way is to create mocked responses and with the help of some variable for switching between using mocks thus returning directly your json or not and making the server call

Comment: https://www.mocky.io use this, easy, simple and nice to use.

Answer (score 2):

Could you consider trying to build mock-up server [JSON server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)

You can create your own JSON format there, e.g:

```
{
"posts": [
{ "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
],
"comments": [
{ "id": 1, "body": "some comment", "postId": 1 }
],
"profile": { "name": "typicode" }
}
```

Then start server:

```
json-server --watch db.json
```

Finally you can query the data using REST endpoint  http://localhost:3000/posts/1 and get:

```
{ "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
```

When your actual backend is ready, just replace the endpoint with the real one.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject code into Foundation's URL loading system and write a custom HTTP handler. Subclass `URLProtocol` and implement it such that the class' object would be instantiated for certain URL requests that your backend is supposed to handle.

e.g.

```swift
public class TestProtocolHandler: URLProtocol {

// ...

override public class func canInit(with task: URLSessionTask) -> Bool {
        guard let request = task.currentRequest else {
            return false
        }
        guard let url = request.url else {
            return false
        }
        // return `true` if your class can handle the `url`.
    }

    // ...

   override public func startLoading() {
        guard let client = self.client else {
            return
        }
        // call methods in `client` as a result of URL loading
    }
}


class YourTestCase: XCTest {

    // use this alternative URLSession for your network clients in test mode
    func makeSession() -> URLSession {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        config.protocolClasses = [
            TestProtocolHandler.self
        ]
        return URLSession(configuration: config)
    }
}
```

Further details in this blog post: [How to Unit Test Network Code in Swift](https://cutecoder.org/programming/unit-test-network-code-swift/).